# Snap Chromium browser and profile problems

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, chromium, snap, sync

After updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 my `chromium` lost it's profile.
After some googling, i found that in 20.04 uses `snap` version of `chromium`.
I copied my profile from `~/.config/chromium/Profile 1` to `~/snap/chromium/current/.config/chromium/Profile 1` and was able to get my opened pages.
Google asked to log me in for sync enablement.
I logged me in, but my stored passwords where not synced.
`Chromium` was not able to fill usernames and passwords in websites.
In `chromium` settings where no websites and passwords visible in password manager.
This problem with sync i had for more than week.
So it is `snap` `chromium` version problem and not sync problem.

How can i sync them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found solution.
I wanted to kill `conky` process, but i hit `chromium` in System monitor.
After `chromium` start with restore previous session, suddenly username and password fill was working!
I checked passwords settings in chromium and everything was present.

So for to restore password sync, it is needed to non-gracefully kill `chromium` and press restore session button.